# matrix form of system of constraints of an optimization problem in Python

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, pyomo

I would like to ask if there is a way in python to obtain the matrix form of a system of constraints of an optimization problem. For example, in MATLAB the function
"problem = prob2struct(prob)" converts an optimization problem or equation problem to solver form and the constraint matrix can be obtained.